# Parse.com : PFRelation With accept or denied

Tags: parse-platform, relation

Hello everyone I would like to know if it 'possible to create pfrelation inserting a chance' to accept or reject the report. P.S. I am following message destructive app thanks

Ps I'm using parse.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance where you would need to create a join table/class manually, e.g.:

```
[SubmittedProjects]
SubmittedBy: relation->User
SubmittedTo: relation->User
Project: relation->Project
Status: string ("pending", "approved", "rejected")
```

You could then easily find all records given a number of parameters, e.g.

- All projects waiting for my approval:

  - SubmittedTo = me
  - Status = "pending"
- People I need to nag to approve/reject my projects:

  - SubmittedFrom = me
  - Status = "pending"
- List of all approved projects:

  - Status = "approved"

Hmm, thinking about it now, these could just be extra fields on your `Project` table if you only have need of one record for each project.

Your question has very little information so please expand it if this isn't what you meant.

Comment: Timothy :D I had already tried to do what you're explaining and worked very well would be nice if we could somehow deal to help me create this thing because I found some difficulty in trying to tell the USER current who are his friends on a TableView I am using a TableView in my viewcontroller with an array that has the function of filter since I have a searchbar to the user search The difficulty here because I'm finding doing a query for the class _USER, then where are all the users, I do not find other data from different classes in the database parse because it is not the same class _USER.

Comment: @TimothyWalters You mentioned on your blog that you would eventually share code regarding your implementation of the above; would you still consider sharing that code?

Comment: @JPK I will if I get time, I'm going through cancer treatment right now though, so my priorities have changed a bit...

Comment: @JPK Well, I decided to go and do it, please have a look at my blog now, I've posted a 3-part series with sample code. Comments welcome!

Comment: It looks great, too bad it is not iOS : ) Also, it doesn't look like you added the code for how to send a request?